# Try download img from firebase storage which link is firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I tried to download the image which is in firebase storage which link is store in database. When I tried to download the image, it takes more time to execute while for loop is completed.

Is there any process that somehow I download in time which doesn't make the function really slow? I already solve this issue using setTimeout but I hope there may be a better solution than mine. Help me! thank you!

```
export const shampooHandler = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(shampooStart());
    const data = [];
    const imgList = [];
    fire
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("Shampoo")
      .once("value")
      .then((response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.val().length; i++) {
          fire.storage().refFromURL(response.val()[i].img).getDownloadURL().then((image) => {
              imgList.push(image);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              dispatch(shampooError(error));
            });
          setTimeout(() => {
            name = response.val()[i].name;
            description = response.val()[i].description;
            value = response.val()[i].value;
            img = imgList[i];
            data.push({ name, description, value, img });
            if (i === (response.val().length - 1)) {
              dispatch(shampooSuccess(data));
            }
          }, 3000);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(shampooError(error));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: I have already declared all the variables before using them.

Comment: Don't use setTimeout.  Use the promises returned by getDownloadURL to determine when the URLs are ready.

Comment: loop completed before downloaded of image and how can we use url to make it ready. Should I create separate promise any use it main function? Can you please evalulate the solution more ?

Answer (score 1):

*I spend a day finding a right solution for it. It may help someone to find solution in future. Thanks guys for giving a thought and specially DougStevensen to tiggering me an idea*

```
export const shampooHandler = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(shampooStart());
    const data = [];
    const imglist = [];
    fire.database().ref().child("Shampoo").once("value").then((response) => {
      response.val().forEach(element => {
        const promise = imageUrlHandler(element.img).then(url => {
          return url;
        }).catch(error =>{
          dispatch(shampooError(error));
        })
        imglist.push(promise);
         //all the promise call to download the images
        Promise.all(imglist).then(items =>{
          const dataCollection = {
            name: element.name,
            description: element.description,
            value: element.value,
            img: items[items.length - 1]
          }
          data.push(dataCollection);
          if(data.length === response.val().length){
            dispatch(shampooSuccess(data));
          }
        }).catch(err =>dispatch(shampooError(err)));
      })

    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch(shampooError(error));
    })
  }
}


export const imageUrlHandler = (databaseUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    fire.storage().refFromURL(databaseUrl).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      resolve(url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    });
  })
}
```